# How to monitor Flink Applications?

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink

One way I know to monitor flink applications from the UI is by adding accumulators and seeing them in UI as described below. 
Is there any other way  ?

Declare Counter :

```
private LongCounter receivedEvents = new LongCounter()
```

Initialize Counter :

```
getRuntimeContext().addAccumulator(RECEIVED_COUNTER, receivedEvents);
getRuntimeContext().addAccumulator(ITEM_FETCH_ERROR_COUNTER, itemFetchError);
```

Update Here :

```
receivedEvents.add(1l); 
anomalyTotalCount.add(1l);
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question? (Also, the screenshot is very blurry.)

Comment: The question was .. Different ways to monitor flink application

Comment: Please edit your question (and its title) to make it clear what you are asking. This will help make the question and its answer(s) more useful to others.